# elif в Python против if в си!

Tags: c, python-3.x, операторы

Вот изучаю Python: не могу понять в чем разница elif в Python 3.0 c if в си????

Comment: Всё тоже самое, в python if elif, в C - if else if, разница в синтаксисе только.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

elif -> else if

elif для упрощения чтения кода, когда надо организовать подобие switch-case